Can I pursue a second CS master's, when I already have one?
I already possess one master's degree in computer science. However, I have now discovered a research idea for which I want to pursue another master's degree in computer science. I am inclined to consequently follow this up with a PhD. I want to do a master's to do initial work to determine the idea's feasibility, and then do a deep dive in my PhD to actually accomplish it. I am in the USA.
My first master's was a coursework/certificate professional degree. I didn't do a thesis and I graduated early.

Is getting a second master's even a good idea? Will my application be even considered?
If so, what specifically are all the questions that my Statement of Purpose needs to answer?
Could mentioning the idea that I later what to do a PhD be a good thing or a bad thing?

3.1 Would it be a good idea to explain that I want to do a Master's to do the initial research to determine the feasibility of the idea, and then followed by a dedicated PhD in this directions?



How can I play this out in a convincing or a reasonable manner?

Why would you not just apply for the PhD directly?  I don't understand the motivation to put another degree in the way of it.

The reputation of the University? Applying for Masters may help me get into more competitive schools compared to the ones I could get into for PhD?

@DeepShrinivasan If you already have a masters, that already gives you a bit of an edge for PhD applications. I highly doubt reputation of the school matters in applications. (For context, I got into one of the top graduate math programs in Texas coming from an institution that just barely started admitting freshmen and sophomores.)

Difference here between "Could I" and "Should I". One way of looking at it, though, is that you already have a taught masters; maybe now, if you can identify the right supervisor, you should be looking at a primarily research-based masters, to do that feasibility work that you mention.

"Applying for Masters may help me get into more competitive schools compared to the ones I could get into for PhD?" This is a bit of a premature conclusion if you have not yet tried applied for PhD programmes. Moreover, if you already have a very specific topic in mind, the key obstacle will be actually finding a willing supervisor who wants to supervise this specific project.

I agree. with your comments about premature conclusion @AdamPřenosil. However, I have seen this first hand with competitive fields like CS.

@SeanRoberson. The thing is, in my case, I simply want to go do a research based masters where I can pursue this idea and determine if this is even possible. Once, I do I want to find a supervisor to help me pursue this idea in a PhD programme.

@Flyto. Thank you that's exactly my plan.

In the US, there would be no need for a second masters almost everywhere and actually no need for any masters (very rare exceptions). The doctoral program in most places is designed to be open to good candidates with only a bachelors.
The question about whether you "can" get a second masters is probably answered "yes, but why". And only an admissions committee can give a final answer. There is nothing in the rules against it, however. And, your coursework masters is probably a plus.
You would be better applying directly to a doctoral program if that is your ultimate goal. You will probably need some class work in any case to enable passing the typical qualifying exams that focus on advanced material.
Once that is done, or nearly done, find an advisor in the subfield of interest and come to a mutually agreed project.
I doubt that a second masters will necessarily be an advantage in getting into a higher rated school. It is a question of things balancing out. The higher up you go, the stiffer the competition. You would have to do extremely well for it to be much of a positive. And, you are delaying a career, most likely.

Thank you for your response @Buffy.

Like I said. Being in the industry, I think I am probably not ready for a full-fledged PhD program. My ultimate goal is to pursue this idea. Which is why I also think that directly enrolling into an PhD without finding a fit (both of my idea and the faculty) in the program  does not seem like a good idea. Therefore, I would like to pursue a research based masters and then enroll in a great university for PhD if I find a fit. i feel like I would be stuck into a long term PhD program if you don't find a fit.
Would love to know if you have more comments on this. @Buffy

Note that a successful doctorate normally requires some negotiation with an advisor on the problem and research area. Coming with a problem you want to work on might work, but it often does not. Be careful.

Thank you so much for your response @Buffy.
I just have one more question and would be glad if you could answer it:
Someone on reddit mentioned for this kind of question that I should first email the university (that I intend to apply to) and ask if they will even consider the application of a student who already has a Masters degree in Computer Science and wants to apply for another.
Do you think it is a good idea? Should I email and ask the university if they will allow someone to pursue a second masters in computer science?
Do you know of any universities who prohibit this?

I doubt it is necessary, but the mail should probably go to the CS department head/chair, not the "university" as a whole. You could phrase it as "Would it be considered a negative that I already hold a MS?".

Thanks @Buffy.
Usually, there is an email for any questions or correspondence beyond/other than the FAQs. Therefore, I am going to use that one. Let me know if you think that's a bad idea.
That phrasing sounds good. Thank you once again.
